# Windows 10 Messaging problems

Tags: windows-10, messaging

My Windows 10 Messaging app seems to have problems.  Until September 10th my SMS messages were showing up.  Now they do not.  I'm running 10.0.14393.447.

The settings page on the Messaging app also looks strange, it looks like:

Settings

```
About this app
Windows Messaging 3.19.1001.0
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation.
All rights reserved
```

That's pretty much it.  There aren't really any settings there.  I also have a Lumia 650 Windows 10 phone that's on anniversary update.

I can't see a way to repair or uninstall/reinstall the Messaging app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [a posting on this site by a Microsoft employee](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/text-messages-sms-notifications-are-no-longer/87266c5e-5131-4e67-be47-6bab98f512a3):

*Hi,
We are temporarily disabling the capability in Cortana on Windows 10 Phone that enables you to receive text messages to your PC. You’ll still be able to receive messages from other services as well as missed calls on your PC. We intend to bring the feature back into the experience soon.*